# Avoid space in class value in scraping in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I was trying to crawl some data from a website. Here I have found space characters in class value in the website like:

```
<div class="Col No 3">
    <div class="row No 4"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case I used:

```
files = bsObj.find_all("div", {"class":"row No 4"})
for file in files:
    print (file.get_text())
```

I have also used (.) dot characters in value in the place of spaces (`"row.No.4"`).

```
files = bsObj.find_all("div", {"class":"row.No.4"})
for file in files:
    print (file.get_text())
```

It still gives an error.

Comment: Okay, so there is an error. What is that error? Knowing the error is important to debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your syntax and content, I assume you are using BeautifulSoup package and want to find files by multiple classes.

Using `.find_all()`:

```
files = bsObj.find_all("div", {"class":['row','No','4']})
for file in files:
    print (file.get_text())
```

On the other hand, If you go for selectors then you need to use dot `.` to join multiple classes:

Using `.select()`:

```
files = bsObj.select("div.row.No.4")
for file in files:
    print (file.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is Working.